# + 4 hours (date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2015-03-01T23:03:03.000Z")))

Tags: php

Why php give such result:

```
var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2015-03-01T23:03:03.000Z")));
```

The result is (+4 hours): `string '2015-03-02 03:03:03'`.

How can I get: `string '2015-03-01 23:03:03'`.

Comment: So what is your default timezone setting? Quoting from the [PHP docs for strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): `Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter.`

Comment: Can't find- what i should write to set -4 hours?

Comment: Use [date_default_timezone_get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) to find out the current timezone setting; and [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to change it if necessary.... or start using PHP's [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)